# Python Pandas convert grouped result to a new list and JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, list

I am new to Python and Pandas, I am trying to get and parse the data from a JSON file, and turn the data to a new list and JSON file.

This is the code I use to get the values.

```
def groupDataByPanda():
    file = open('/Users/bryce/Desktop/Dengue_Daily_10.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    df = pd.read_json(file)
    date_group = df.groupby(['date'])
    df = date_city_group = date_group['city'].value_counts()

    print(df)
    df.to_json(r'Result.json', orient='records')
```

The value is correct when I print(df), but when I try df.values.tolist(), it turns to a list of [2, 2, 1, 1...] without any dates and city names.

[image]

How can I turn the df to a list like this and write to a new JOSN file.

[image]

The JSON file:

```
 [{"date":"1998/01/02","case_study":"None","notice_date":"1998/01/07","gender":"m","age":"40-44","city":"London","vell":"None","min_area":"A1320-0136-00","min_X":"120.505898941","min_Y":"22.464206650","unit_area":"A1320-04-008","second_code":"A1320-04","inflict_city":"None","inflict_town":"None","inv":"None","outsider":"no","inflict_country":"None","scode":"1"},
...
]
```

Comment: please paste in `/Users/bryce/Desktop/Dengue_Daily_10.json'

Comment: Please check your path.

Comment: @KritiPawar The path is correct, I can read and work with data from the JSON file. But I cannot turn the result into a list with the correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
from collections import Counter
def count_city(x):
    return dict(Counter(x))

def groupDataByPanda():
    file = open('/Users/bryce/Desktop/Dengue_Daily_10.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    df = pd.read_json(file)
    res = df.groupby('date').agg({
        'city': [('count', count_city)],
    })
    res.columns = res.columns.droplevel()
    res.reset_index(inplace=True) 
    data = res.to_dict(orient="records")
    final_json = [dict({"date":x["date"]},**x["count"]) for x in data]
    print(final_json)
```

Hope this helps!!